# setting up spring and maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am creating environment for setting up a spring project using maven , spring.

But i am getting error while trying to execute this URL
http://localhost:8080/assignment2_farooqab/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp[^]

The Error is
HTTP Status 404
The resource is not available

I think the problem is due to this file mvcdispather xml

<

```
beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2_farooqab" />

        <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix">
                        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
                </property>
                <property name="suffix">
                        <value>.jsp</value>
                </property>
        </bean>

</beans>
```

basecontroller.java file is

```
package no.uio.inf5750.assignment2_farooqab.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;


@Controller
public class BaseController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String welcome(ModelMap model) {

                model.addAttribute("message", "Maven Web Project + Spring 3 MVC - welcome()");

                //Spring uses InternalResourceViewResolver and return back index.jsp
                return "index";

        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/welcome/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String welcomeName(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) {

                model.addAttribute("message", "Maven Web Project + Spring 3 MVC - " + name);
                return "index";

        }

}
```

any tips

Comment: Thats because `http://localhost:8080/assignment2_farooqab/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp` isnt mapped in your controllers. Try going to `http://localhost:8080/assignment2_farooqab/`. The pages available are designated by your annotations in your controller not by where you put your jsp files in the WEB-INF folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by your code `return "index";` and your view resolver you forward your view resolver to path

> /WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp

and `@RequestMapping` annotation is binding this page to website address via `value="/"` or `"/welcome/{name}"` so basicly all you have to do is call your application via links

> http://localhost:8080/assignment2_farooqab
>   or
>   http://localhost:8080/assignment2_farooqab/welcome/test